# In the quest "the search for mandragora" where is the pot exactly?

Tags: unepic

In this game Unepic there is a quest "The search for Mandragora" for which you need to find  a white pot in which you can keep the uprooted Mandragora plant. Does anyone have any idea where the hell the stupid pot is? I've spent about 3 hours looking for that useless item and even gone through a youtube video but can't find exactly where he picks it up.

Answer (score 5):

From the golden room where you received the quest, go 2 map squares down and 3 to the right. (Look on the map; you'll be two map squares below a gate entrance, and the rightmost in a line of green squares.) Kill all wasps **AND THE HIVE!** A ladder will appear in the upper right corner. There is the pot you are looking for.

Comment: Urgh! I would never have found that.. thanks for your help!!